# Can "too" occur in a negative sentence? "That effort too came to nothing"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-structure, adverbs, idiomatic-language

The following sentence is from the BBC web site [Trapped](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-62903758)

**That effort too came to nothing.**

We were taught in English classes that **too** can be used in positive sentences, and **either** in negative sentences.

So, why was **"too"** used in this negative sentence?

Comment: It should be noted that "positive" in this sense refers to sentences that affirm or confirm something, while "negative" refers to a denial.  It has nothing to do with whether the sentence is saying good, happy things or not.  As an example, "I hate you too." is a valid and normal sentence.

Comment: _Side note:_ Changing _That effort too came to nothing._ into _That effort, too, came to nothing._ looks better to me. That's to indicate a slight pause around "too" when speaking. But, changing _too_ to _also_, the sentence pronunciation seems correct to me either way (with or without the pause) with slightly different emphasis in each case. I would usually prefer _also_ over _too_ in this context.

Answer (score 27):

(Converted my comment to an answer, since it has been upvoted.)

*Came to nothing* has a negative meaning but it isn't grammatically negative. A negative sentence would be 'That effort did not come to anything either', though in my opinion it doesn't sound as good.

Comment: Interesting. Would you say "President X failed to get reelected" was a positive (not a  negative) sentence? So: *"GHW Bush failed to get reelected in 1992, President Trump failed too in 2020"*. I guess the key distinction to draw is that the sentence is **linguistically* positive.

Comment: @smci - Thay is what I was trying to convey.

Comment: @smci The grammatical positive/negative distinction isn't about a moral or value judgement, it is about whether the verb is negated or not.  Four quick examples: "Alice did get hired.  Bob didn't get hired.  Chad did get fired.  Dan didn't get fired." Examples A and C are positive "did" examples, whereas B and D are negative "didn't" examples... even though we might all agree that the situations described in A/D are "good" compared to the "bad" B/C situations.

Comment: @AmateurDotCounter: yes I already understood that and that was exactly what I was saying. I was saying it was worth spelling out very explicitly in the answer, more than it currently is.

Comment: @KateBunting: Right, we agree. I was saying this subtle point is worth spelling out very explicitly in the answer, more than it currently is.

Comment: In the abstract, the negatively formulated version with "either" sounds a lot better to me.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you're right.

We do not usually use also, as well and **too** in negative sentences. We use **not**...**either** in negative sentences.

Positive: I like you **too**. Negative: I do **not** like you **either**.

Positive: I like you **as well**. Negative: I do **not** like you  **either**.

Positive: **That effort too came to nothing**.

Negative: **That effort did not come to anything either**.

**Nothing** is used in positive statements. **Anything** is used in negative statements.

When we use negative words such as nobody, or nothing, we do not use a negative verb.

He says **nothing** or He **does not** say **anything** (NOT 'He does not say nothing')

'That effort too came to nothing' is stronger and more definite than 'That effort did not come to anything either'.

Comment: In other words, the negativity of a sentence is based on the presence of the core auxiliary "not" (and its contracted forms like "didn't" etc), but not all words with a negative meaning like "nothing".

Comment: Following up on the last comment, it really is the structure "not [verb] anything" that tells you you have a negative statement. The word "anything" by itself can also be used in positive statements: "I would do anything for love." "I too would do anything for love."

Comment: @David K "... but I wouldn't do that." "I wouldn't do that either."

Comment: One of the problems with this answer is that it is a bit vague about what a "negative sentence" is. For instance, _I do not like it, but I don't dislike it either. I'm neutral_. How would that be analyzed? And what exactly it the "negative verb"? _He stays silent about nothing_ is reasonable enough.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, 'too' in that context means 'also' or 'as well'.

The 'too' referred to 'that effort': "That effort also came to nothing".

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that grammar cares naught for feelings.

Grammatically, a sentence either uses **negation** or it doesn't, and based on *that* one uses either *too* or *either*:

- *That effort too came to nothing*: no negation, so we use *too* and *nothing*.
- *That effort did not come to anything either*: negation, so we use *either* and *anything*.

Both sentences convey similar (negative) feelings, which grammar doesn't care about in any way.

Another example would be: *I like you too* <=> *I do not hate you either*. Both convey positive feelings, and can use either *too* or *either*.

Comment: I think this is more clearly stated as **"linguistically positive", even if it wouldn't be considered "semantically positive"**. Per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but ***"syntactically positive"*** not "semantically positive"; so the OP's sentence is actually *syntactically* not negative:

To clarify this nuance, per @KateBunting's answer, the following example can use "too" since it is "syntactically positive", i.e. the verb isn't negated:

- *"In 1980, President Carter failed to get reelected, mainly due to a recession. In 1992, President GHW Bush failed too, and for the same reason."*

*"X failed to do Y"* is "syntactically positive", even if we wouldn't consider it "semantically positive" for X's political fortunes.

Comment: "Grammatically" or "syntactically" positive or negative would be a more accurate term.  Linguistics is a broad field that includes semantics and pragmatics as well as syntax, so "linguistically" could encompass any of those levels.

Comment: @JohnVelonis: ok, *"syntactically"*